# Setting up replacement rpi Model B 512MB

Tags: boot

I recently bought a (new) Model B Rpi 2011/2012 512MB to replace another identical model.
I also added the same Wolfson audio card that the old Rpi had, and put the two connected items into a case.

I then took the SD card from the old rpi, expecting it to start up in the same way as the original as they seem to be identical.
I am using terminal rather than a monitor and keyboard.

The new pi does not appear on the network and I am wondering if I am missing out a step in setting up the new kit.

Would welcome any advice, thanks

Comment: Without knowing what OS, how you configured networking any why you needed to "replace another identical model" this is unanswerable - although you will probably get lots of idle speculation

Comment: Thanks.  I suppose the underlying question is if two sets of hardware are seemingly identical in all respects, is it possible to simply swap an SD card between the sets? Or is further specific configuration required of the new set of hardware?

Comment: you can, with some caveats, use the same sd card in 0, 0W, A, B, 2 (both revisions), 3, 3A+, 3B+ and 4 .... of course, only buster images work in 4, not sure about limitation for the others - so, moving an SD card from a B to a B is trivial

Comment: "I am using terminal" - what sort of terminal? or is terminal a program on some other computer?

Comment: Yes, with the original hardware I was logging in remotely using an SSH connection via the Terminal application of a Mac, and hoping to do the same with the new hardware

Comment: how? using an IP address or raspberrypi.local

Comment: I have been using the IP address e.g. ssh pi@192.168.1.XXX

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109908/discussion-between-northdown-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How do you check whether it "appears on the network"? It is very likely that the new Pi gets another IP from your router than the old one did, because that is usually determined by the MAC address of the device. The easiest way to find the new PIs IP is usually to check in the configuration pages of your router. There's usually a page (maybe only in expert mode) that shows all the devices connected to it and their IPs.

Comment: Thanks. I have been accessing the 'My Network'  part of the router webpages and the device doesn't appear there.

Comment: Check if it has an IP-number assigned using ifconfig.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to set up last night with an 2015-05-05 raspian wheezy though mouse and keyboard do not seem to be recognised ( I am using raspberry pi branded power 5.1v, and the USB devices work fine on other machines) - it seems i have no way of interacting with the Pi, and wondering if it is defective? Using the 2015 wheezy image on booting I arrive at the raspi-config screen, but unable to procress with non functioning USB devices

Comment: Mouse and Keyboard not working is pretty strange, indeed. But why did you try with such an old image? The raspberry firmware is constantly improved, so this may also explain USB issues. To make sure the Pi is not deffective, try with a recent Noobs image, then you can be sure it is technically working (or not).

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to use an old Wolfson audio card with it the pi model B so used an older version that I had successfully used in the past. I also tried the current version of Debian 32-bit with similar results on the USB and networking. I'll give Noobs a try in any case, but coming round more to the idea the Pi is defective

Answer (score 3):

Although the hardware might be techically the same, at least the MAC Address of the Ethernet device is different. If you have some configuration tied to the MAC Address, that configuration must be updated to the new MAC Address of the Ethernet port.

Comment: Many thanks. Do you know if it is possible to edit the SD card?

Comment: why would you edit the SD card? the configuration in this answer refers to router (DHCP server) configuration of "reserved IP based on MAC address" ...

Comment: Thanks. The new Pi now appears on the on the network (via ethernet) with a DHCP assigned IP address, though any communication with the new Pi via SSH seems to time out. The old Pi had a static IP (according to the router this was assigned by the Pi). I am wondering whether I need to amend the configuration to somehow remove the fixed IP address.

Comment: If the old PI had a fixed IP configured (not set by the router), then this should normally be taken over to the new PI as well, since you swapped the SD card. Looks more like your Pi is not booting. Can you see the green light flashing while it boots? I suggest you attach a screen to it to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. On the old set up - there are 2 sets of LED: adjacent to USB are row of 5 LEDS that light up as follows: yellow, flashing green, green, red, green; & adjacent to power 2 LEDS: green and red, now green only.

Comment: On the new set up (using the same SD card) - the LEDs are as follows: adjacent to USB 5 LEDS that light up as follows: yellow (intermittent flash) , green (intermittent flash), green (intermittent flash), red, green (intermittent flash); & adjacent to power 2 LEDS: green and red, (was briefly green only, then both red and green)

Comment: realised that the two LEDs next to power are associated with the Wolfson audio card (the pi & card are inside a case)

Comment: Thanks. I was able to attach a screen, an old keyboard and mouse last night. I thought i would try to go back to basics and simplify by using a series of images of the OS. In each case the keyboard caused a crash / panic on start up - endless lines of text. The mouse moved but difficult to control. In each case the ethernet network symbol top right on the screen had two red crosses across the arrows. Unfortunately not possible to interact with the machine or code and now I am wondering if the OS or the Pi itself is defective in some way

Answer (score 2):

thanks all for help with this - i shall pursue this, found on eLinux.org

In some distributions, /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules remembers which MAC address is associated with eth0, so each new device will be assigned as a different interface (eth1, eth2, etc.) due to the different MAC addresses. Editing /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules to remove the invalid rules and rebooting may help fix the problem.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score -1):

If you are connecting via Wi-Fi, you need to connect your new Pi to the Wi-Fi network and enter the password. I discovered this recently (on a Pi Zero W), thinking that I could just swap the SD card and all the settings would transfer.

I only found that it wasn't connecting when I connected a monitor to the Pi.

Comment: the model B does not have onboard wifi, and since wifi wasn't mentioned in the question, it's safe to assume wifi isn't at play